# Facebook graph API insights gives post_video_views_organic for photo post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are fetching insights of posts in our app via fb graph api v2.7

We have noticed that we are getting video_views_organic value for posts other than videos such as photo post.

Can anyone please let me know if this is correct behavior from api?

Thanks,
Kinnari